# 2 class dependencies?

Tags: java, class

I am making an Java Swing GUI application. I have 2 classes that are causing me a problem. I have created an menubar Class that handles normal menubar options:

```
File -> Exit
Edit -> Cut, Copy , Paste
Tools -> Options 
Help -> About
```

The last class is an Options class. That currently just updates the JFrame to what swing look and feel you want via a JComboBox. MercuryFrame is just my default JFrame for the UI.

Currently the code is

```
OptionWindow option = new OptionWindow( mercuryFrame , notesWindow ); 
MercuryMenuBar menuBar = new MercuryMenuBar( mercuryFrame , option );
```

Now the issue I am having is I want our menuBar class to have a JFrame to display whenever About is clicked. That shows lets say the current version. Now in this setup the optionWindow will not update the JFrame for About. Now I can fix this by lets saying passing the value when I call the optionWindow Function.

```
openOptionWindow(menuBarJFrame);
```

or after the class declarations using a setter method

```
option.setHelpFrame(JFrame);
```

lastly the other option that I considered would be making the About its own class and just passing it to both of them.

```
AboutWindow  about = new AboutWindow();
OptionWindow option = new OptionWindow( mercuryFrame , notesWindow , about ); 
MercuryMenuBar menuBar = new MercuryMenuBar( mercuryFrame , option , about );
```

Are any of these methods the correct approach? or is it an issue with how I am designing it?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

I went with the third approach.

```
AboutWindow  about = new AboutWindow();
OptionWindow option = new OptionWindow( mercuryFrame , notesWindow , about ); 
MercuryMenuBar menuBar = new MercuryMenuBar( mercuryFrame , option , about );
```

But I would love to hear if you think this is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the third approach.

```
AboutWindow  about = new AboutWindow();
OptionWindow option = new OptionWindow( mercuryFrame , notesWindow , about ); 
MercuryMenuBar menuBar = new MercuryMenuBar( mercuryFrame , option , about );
```